# Generic way to get mail provider email account aliases for mail client to use as Send From

Tags: email, imap, alias

I have an IMAP account for a domain and I have setup aliases in, the IMAP account provider, to help me separate out my email for different things e.g. sales@ support@ etc.

Is there a generic way for a mail client to fetch these aliases from the mail provider so that I can use a drop-down in the compose message to select which alias I want to send from?

Thunderbird offers customise from address but it doesn't provide a way to remember these for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Each mail-client does things differently, or so it would seem.

The approach I use, and which applied to any mail-client I ever used, is simply to threat those aliases as being independent mailboxes and to configure the client for multiple mail-boxes (one for each alias). You just don't retrieve mail on the alias boxes.

That should give you the option to set the sender for each mail to whatever alias you want.

You may have to explicitly configure the mail-client to NOT retrieve mail for the alias-mailboxes.
If that is technically not possible in your client you may have to intentionally configure an incorrect IMAP or POP3 server for the aliases, so it really can't poll them.
Only setup the outgoing part correctly. And ignore the errors the mail-clients gives about "not being able to retrieve email".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware the server does not track aliases in a way that they could be configured automatically.  Instead it's just a list the server uses to deliver mail to the right real mailbox.

> Thunderbird offers customise from address but it doesn't provide a way to remember these for next time.

This however, is incorrect.  You can setup all your custom aliases in Thunderbird and have them available to select in the From menu permanently.  This feature [is known as Identities](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/using-identities) and is configured in the account settings.

To add an identity:

1. Right click your account name and select `Settings`
2. Click the `Manage Identities...` button at the bottom of the settings window
3. Click `Add...` in the identities popup
4. Fill out the name and email address you want to use.  There are several other identity specific settings you can set as well.

After your identities are setup, they can be selected in the `From` line when composing a message using that account.